# Building query for query attribute task in arcgis server manager for a layer related to a table

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server

I my map document (.mxd), one layer (BUILDING with spatial data) is RELATED to a stand-alone table (EMPLOYEE) with one-to-many relationship having a common field call dept number (one building with a dept number can have many employees with same dept number in EMPLOYEE table). How do I build a query for Query Attribute Task through Arcgis Server Manager because when I choose BUILDING as my layer, it doesn't show EMPLOYEE table attribute. What I intended to write a equivalent sql query as "select * from building, employee where building.dept_no = employee.dept_no". I don't see a way to put this in arcgis server manager. Can anybody please help.

Thanks,
Archana